# Listening on NSNotificationCenter messages in react-native app

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to listen to some messages from `NSNotificationCenter` in my app and send out events to JS side when some messages are received. Mainly, I am interested in message `NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification` which can be used to detect if the user's device time zone has changed. I have added following code in `AppDelegate.swift` for this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  // Existing code
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.timezoneChanged), name: NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

func timezoneChanged() {
  let appEventEmitter = self.bridge.moduleForClass(AppEventEmitter) as! AppEventEmitter
  appEventEmitter.sendEventWithName("timezoneChanged", body:nil)
}
```

After this change, if I change the timezone on my phone and go to the app, the `timezoneChanged` function is invoked but I see an exception in code right away and the application crashes

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I guess the problem is with `appEventEmitter`. I am using exact some code in other parts of the app to send an event to JS side but I don't know why does it not work here. If I change the `timezoneChanged` function implementation to just a print statement, then I am able to see the print statement and the app doesn't crash.

I don't know Swift language as such and not sure how to debug this problem. Please let me know if you have any pointers that can help in debugging this problem.